# Custmizing Django formwizard interface

Tags: python, django, python-3.1

How to Customize Django form wizard interface,how to impliment our methods inside session wizard interface class

Comment: What have you already tried to do?

Comment: You should add *a lot* more details to your question. What you have done so far (as a minimal example) as well what is not working with your approach and what you expect from a working  solution.